# Несколько sql запросов

Tags: php, mysql

Всем Привет.
Вопрос может и банальный но решения пока не нашел.
Выбираю из БД то что мне нужно:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `members`";

$result = $db->query($sql); 

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{

    $balans = $row['balans'];
    $email = $row['email']; 
    $username =$row['username'];

    echo "Баланс: $row[balans]. Юзер: $row[username]. Почта: $row[email].<br>"; 
}
```

Но еще хочется просуммировать допустим баланс и пользователей и вывести echo.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `members`";
```

Как вопрос реализовать и допустимо ли на одной странице несколько в данном случае $sql запросов. Спасибо

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под фразой просуммировать пользователей?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count_members, SUM(balans) as total_balans FROM `members`
```

Answer (score 0):

Сумму и кол-во пользователей можно подсчитать прямо в скрипте:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `members`";
$result = $db->query($sql);
$sum = 0;
$count = 0;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{

    $balans = $row['balans'];
    $email = $row['email']; 
    $username =$row['username'];
    $sum += $row['balans'];
    $count++;

    echo "Баланс: $row[balans]. Юзер: $row[username]. Почта: $row[email].<br>"; 
}

echo "Всего пользователей: " . $count . "<br>";
echo "Общая сумма: " . $sum . "<br>";
```

В целом запросов на одной странице может быть столько, сколько вам нужно. Хоть 1000. Но каждый запрос увеличивает время выполнения скрипта.

Comment: Спасибо))) Работает.

Comment: @JoinJexon, на этом сайте вместо спасибо принимают ответ как ответ на свой вопрос и +1 ставят)